# Claim type coming as a "emails" and then ClaimTypes.Email getting null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

```
var userEmail = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email); --> getting null
var email = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "emails")?.Value; --> getting valid email

options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
```

I'm working on .net core 5.My issue is  c.type getting as emails That's why its returning null. Any idea about this?

Comment: `ClaimTypes.Email` gives you `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress`, and the other one you are searching for is `emails`

Answer (score 1):

Probably your claims are *custom* defined.
So, the standard value for `ClaimTypes.Email` is defined in **System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes**

```
        internal const string ClaimType2005Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims";
...
        public const string Email = ClaimType2005Namespace + "/emailaddress";
```

instead your claim for email is defined as "emails".

Have you any custom definition in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a custom claim mapping that maps `emails` claim in JWT to `ClaimTypes.Email`.

```cs
services
    .AddAuthentication(...)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options => {
        // ...
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(claimType: ClaimTypes.Email, jsonKey: "emails");
    })
```